# Subsocial tokens to create profile

Tags: token, subsocial

Where can I acquire `subsocial tokens` so I can start using that platform. I see that there's a `faucet` but when I go to the faucet it says that's no longer available because of main net launch. But that leaves me still unable to create my profile because I can't find the token anywhere. Is there an `ETA` for availability?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment it's not possible, but they're working on it.

Take a look at their FAQ: https://docs.subsocial.network/docs/faq/overview#how-can-i-buy-subsocial-tokens

Answer (score 1):

DM @SubsocialChain nicely on twitter and they might send you one if you send them your address and say you'd like to start blogging. Someone nice on here might but you'd need to stick your address in to meet us half way :-)

They said that they would be starting to distribute the crowdloan tokens shortly. I would expect that they might be easier to come by after that. But yes it's a bit frustrating in these in-between times.